# A lot if and else conditions repeating code

Tags: c#

I have a scenario where I do filters depending of checkbox checked, now I have only 2 checkbox and I need to cover all scenarios into if, else conditionals like:

```
//List Example:
 var projectTechnicians = (from DataRow dr in dtEmployeGuid.Rows
                                      where dr["Title"].ToString().Contains("Project Technician")
                                      select new
                                      {
                                          EmpGuid = (Guid)dr["EmpGuid"]
                                      }).ToList();




if (!chkProjectTechs.Checked && !chkTeamLeader.Checked)
{
    foreach (DataRowView list in lstTech.SelectedItems)
    {
        var selectedEmpGuid = (Guid)list[0];
        EmpGuid.Add(selectedEmpGuid);
    }
    parameters = ToDataTable(EmpGuid);
}
else if (!chkTeamLeader.Checked && chkProjectTechs.Checked)
{
    foreach (var technician in projectTechnicians)
    {
        EmpGuid.Add(technician.EmpGuid);
    }
    parameters = ToDataTable(EmpGuid);
}
else if (!chkProjectTechs.Checked && chkTeamLeader.Checked)
{
    foreach (var teamLeader in teamLeaders)
    {
        EmpGuid.Add(teamLeader.EmpGuid);
    }
    parameters = ToDataTable(EmpGuid);
}
else if (chkProjectTechs.Checked && chkTeamLeader.Checked)
{
    foreach (var technician in projectTechnicians)
    {
        EmpGuid.Add(technician.EmpGuid);
    }
    parameters = ToDataTable(EmpGuid);

    foreach (var teamLeader in teamLeaders)
    {
        EmpGuid.Add(teamLeader.EmpGuid);
    }
    parameters = ToDataTable(EmpGuid);
}
```

But I need to Add more checkbox, but foreach checkbox I will add to my form  I need to add it to each conditional, and at the final of the day I will get a very long code. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: To start you don't need to have `parameters = ToDataTable(EmpGuid);` inside each block.

Comment: Isn't the 4th `else if` the sum of the 2nd and the 3rd? Use two `if` rather than 3 `else if` there.

Comment: u r using 2 kind of foreach loops at so many places, put each one of them in a method ( function ) and just call them with 1 word where u need the loop to execute. and your code will reduce a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an issue in you last `else if` condition. `parameters` is getting overwritten by teamleaders empGuids

```
foreach (var technician in projectTechnicians)
    {
        EmpGuid.Add(technician.EmpGuid);
    }
    parameters = ToDataTable(EmpGuid);

    foreach (var teamLeader in teamLeaders)
    {
        EmpGuid.Add(teamLeader.EmpGuid);
    }
    parameters = ToDataTable(EmpGuid); // Overwriting projectTechnicians added above.
```

You can simplify your code by using if condition only, check my comments in the code.

```
// add EmpGuids from lstTech if no check box is selected.
// you need to add all checkboxes not selected in the condition
if (!chkProjectTechs.Checked && !chkTeamLeader.Checked)
{
    foreach (DataRowView list in lstTech.SelectedItems)
    {
        var selectedEmpGuid = (Guid)list[0];
        EmpGuid.Add(selectedEmpGuid);
    }
}

// if projectTechnicians is checked, then add projectTechnicians EmpGuids to parameters
if (chkProjectTechs.Checked)
{
    foreach (var technician in projectTechnicians)
    {
        EmpGuid.Add(technician.EmpGuid);
    }
}

// add team leader Empguids if checked.
if (chkTeamLeader.Checked)
{
    foreach (var teamLeader in teamLeaders)
    {
        EmpGuid.Add(teamLeader.EmpGuid);
    }
}

// Add new checkbox conditions here
//

// perform your next operation on parameters here. 
// At this point you will have either lstTech employees or employees based on checkbox selection in EmpGuid list.
parameters = ToDataTable(EmpGuid);
```

**EDIT**
if you are using LINQ, then you can use below LINQ query to add EmpGuids instead of using `foreach`, for example.

```
EmpGuid.AddRange(teamLeader.Select(x=>x.EmpGuid));
```

Comment: Also, its good to add a foreach? there is not another approach instead foreach?

Comment: just added another approach using LINQ at the end my answer.